# JavaScript Canvas Feather Arc

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm currently drawing arcs with the canvas tag and I've been asked if I can feather (soften) the edges of the arcs. Is this possible? Googling and searching on here it seems like more hassle than it's worth.

I've tried looking on mdn too but resources for feathering an element seem sparse.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of what you're asking for? I *think* I know but I don't want to spend time on a demo and be way off.

Comment: So I am looking for an effect along these lines to use with a clearArc prototype I found on the internet. If it's possible it's not a deal breaker if it can't be done. http://www.jma.duq.edu/classes/shepherd/jma260-03-and-04/Photoshop/Toolbox/feather-ex.jpg

Comment: Have you tried using shadowColor/shadowBlur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the image you link to in your comment, it seems you're trying to do a shadow.

If this is the case, you can do this :

[image]

With this code :

```
c.beginPath();
c.arc(33, 33, 22, 0, Math.PI, false);
c.shadowOffsetX = 2;
c.shadowOffsetY = 2;
c.shadowBlur = 5;
c.shadowColor  = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)';
c.fillStyle = "red";
c.fill();
```

​
[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/anEvh/)

Or maybe you're trying to do this :

[image]

```
c.beginPath();
c.arc(33, 33, 22, 10, Math.PI*2, false);
c.lineWidth = 2;
var gradient = c.createLinearGradient(20, 0, 50, 40);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "white");
gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'red');
gradient.addColorStop(1, "white");
c.strokeStyle = gradient;
c.stroke();
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Su8Gb/)

Comment: This looks like it would do the trick, Unfortunately I can't try this right now but I will have a look tomorrow and let you know how I get on.

Comment: It was close but not quite there, I really appreciate the time you put in and I've marked it as the solution since it was close enough but not perfect, didn't perform very well on an iPad with the touch events. I've ditched the idea but again, thanks.

Comment: Is this the best approach still in 2020? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately no feather option (yet), but someone who answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010835/how-to-create-soft-stroke-edge-using-html5-canvas)
came up a this fiddle which comes probably pretty close to what you want to achieve using RGBA gradients:

```
gradient.addColorStop(0,    "rgba("+r+","+g+","+b+",0)");
```

See his jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/chdh/MmYAt/

But it still is a bit of a hassle. I would like to submit a feature request for this but I simply have no idea where?